# RedBeanPHP consumes all memory

Tags: php, redbean

I've run into an issue where PHP process gets out of memory when there's too many beans found. E.g. when doing

```
$rows = R::find('myTable', 'id > 0');
```

and when there's 20k rows, PHP crashes. Is there a way to perhaps iterate through the result-set somehow, without consuming all available memory?

Comment: RedBeanPHP is a great tool, but I don't think it's really suitable for huge databases. Is your db frozen, your cache enabled ?

Comment: Also check that you id is indexed (but since it is RB it should automatically be indexed).  I use RB for 100k rows and no issues. So why would you ask for id>0 that is just the same as asking for R::find("myTable") and you want 20k rows back.  You need to change the query.

Comment: John, that was just an example.

Comment: John, also, our production server has memory limitations per process.

Comment: Have you tried R::freeze()? Freezing the schema significantly reduces memory footprint.